# IBAction inside UITableViewCell not called in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ibaction

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass which contains a few `IBAction` methods wired up from a nib.

Under iOS 8 everything works as expected. If the user taps one of the buttons, the appropriate `IBAction` is called.  If the user taps anywhere else on the cell, the `UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called.

Under iOS 9, my IBAction methods are never called. The `UITableView` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is always fired regardless of where the user taps in the cell (button or not).

The project is compiled under Xcode 6 / Swift 1.2.

I found this post on an Apple forum w/ no solution.  They seem to have the same issue.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16179

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I figured out the solution, hopefully this answer will save someone else the time.

I inherited this code base and it had some issues. The `UITableViewCell's` that were not working under iOS 9 were not using `UITableViewCell` nibs w/ a `ContentView`.  Instead, someone had created a `UIView` nib and then pointed it to a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.  The nibs did not have a `ContentView` and apparently iOS 9 is a little more picky about that. This implementation worked fine under iOS 8 and there were no compiler or runtime errors or warnings.

The solution was to create a new `UITableViewCell` subclass and let Xcode auto create the nib for it.  Then I copied over all of the UI and code from the old nib and pasted it into the `ContentView` of the new nib.  I then had to fix up the constraints and rewire the connections to the custom subclass.

Comment: Or just add UITableViewCell from objects library in the same xib file, copypaste/relayout/relink IBOutlets/set base class, then remove old view.

Comment: Thanks for this! Really frustrating.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing. Wasted my whole day on this until I saw your answer.

Comment: Nice answer! I had this problema with legacy project. Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, waste half a day on it(

Comment: For me it was that the XIB I used as a collection view cell was of type, well, **View**. I've removed it and created a new class which extends `UICollectionViewCell`, and checked the **Also create XIB file** option. This created a XIB of type **CellView** instead of just **View**. The whole codebase remained the same, the only difference was that I was able to click the buttons in the cell now instead of always reaching CollectionView's `didSelectItemAt` when trying to.

Answer (score 17):

Just add this line in `tableView` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = false;
return cell;
```

but this is not a proper solution.

iOS 9, puts a content view to a `tableViewCell`, even though you use a custom cell/xib. The content view being added after the custom cell, it was on top of it.

To solve this properly just replace custom cell/xib's view with `UITableviewCell` from object library [from where you usually drag&drop `UIButton`, `UILabel`, etc...];

Comment: This is an excellent solution if you want a quick fix. I was using a 3rd party framework that stopped working. All I had to do was disable userinterations on the contentview. I did this in initWithCoder (it was a nib file).