# Cannot edit fields in custom UITableViewCell (iOS 9)

Tags: cocoa, ios9, xcode7

after upgrading to iOS 9 (worked fine in iOS 8), I am having trouble clicking UIBUttons and editing UITextFields inside custom UITableViewCells.

I have an UITableView with custom UITableViewCells. These cells are loaded like this:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...
        controller=[[PresetRowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PresetRowViewController" bundle:nil];
...
    return (UITableViewCell *)controller.view;
}`

The cells show fine, but I cannot click in any UIButton or edit any UITextField inside them.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for gesture recognizers (ie. `view.gestureRecognizers = nil;`) for various views (the button, cell itself). Also make sure `button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` and `cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` Finally, make sure there's no invisible views overtop of the button/cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bring the subviews in the customized table view cell to the front.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Apple changed how `UITableViewCell`s work in iOS 9. It was fixed for me by dragging in a new `UITableViewCell` into the Xib and moving everything over. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32826526/101923