# Swift - Connect Delegate to Custom Xib Cell

Tags: swift, xcode, xib, swift-protocols

**[SOLVED]**

**Solution**

When created a Xib File , I hadn't deleted the start UIView. Whereas I had to delete this view and after add new CollectionViewCell in this xib.

Reference: [IBAction inside UITableViewCell not called in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705171/ibaction-inside-uitableviewcell-not-called-in-ios-9/32826526#32826526)

---

I use this structure so many times.When I write this delegate with using StoryBoard , it works properly but now it's not. Where is my mistake when use the xib files?

**print(indexpath)** doesn't work!

```
import UIKit

class SearchVC: UIViewController {

var searchUid:String?
var comingPage:String?
var searchElements = [ProductElement]()

var collection:UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if comingPage == "ProductVC" {
        print(searchUid!)
    }

    let searchView : SearchListView = UIView.fromNib()
    searchView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(searchView)

    searchView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeTopAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    searchView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeBottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    searchView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeRightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    searchView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeLeftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    searchView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    collection = searchView.collectionView
    collection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    collection.delegate = self
    collection.dataSource = self

    collection.register(UINib(nibName: "SearchCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SearchCollectionCell")



    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    collection.collectionViewLayout = layout

    GetElements().search(keywords: ["\(searchUid!)"], contentTypes: ["contenttype_article"]) { (elements) in
        self.searchElements = elements
        self.collection.reloadData()
    }

}

}

extension SearchVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchElements.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell: SearchCollectionCell! = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SearchCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? SearchCollectionCell

    if cell == nil {
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "SearchCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SearchCollectionCell")
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SearchCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? SearchCollectionCell

    }



    let url = URL(string: "\(String(describing: Config.fileServiceWFileUid!))\(String(describing: searchElements[indexPath.row].oneImage!))")
    cell.searchImage.kf.setImage(with: url)

    cell.productName.text = searchElements[indexPath.row].title
    cell.productCompany.text = searchElements[indexPath.row].description
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2 - 5 , height: 175)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   // print(indexPath.row)
}

}

extension SearchVC : SearchCollectionCellDelegate {

func searchCellShareButton(sender: SearchCollectionCell) {
    print("AA")
    if let indexpath = collection.indexPath(for: sender) {
        print(indexpath)
    }
}

}
```

//

```
protocol SearchCollectionCellDelegate{
    func searchCellShareButton(sender:SearchCollectionCell)
}

class SearchCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet var searchImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var productName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var productCompany: UILabel!

var delegate:SearchCollectionCellDelegate?

override func layoutSubviews() {
    searchImage.layer.cornerRadius = 4
}

@IBAction func cellShareButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    if delegate != nil {
        delegate?.searchCellShareButton(sender: self)
    }

}
}
```

[image]
**[EDIT]**

I added didSelectItemAt func. When I try to press "..." button for calling protocol, didSelectItemAt works. I think also this is another mistake.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

**[EDIT 2]**

AddTarget Action didn't work. Where is my mistake? Please help me!!!

```
@IBOutlet var shareButton: UIButton!

weak var delegate:SearchCollectionCellDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    shareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(asd), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func asd(){
    print("asd")
}
```

Comment: is it giving error or not printing indexpath

Comment: not printing indexpath!

Comment: You need to connect button with action `cellShareButtonAction` in your `Xib`.

Comment: make a break point in delegate method and see if you are getting in if let clause or not

Comment: have you given xib reuse identifier in storyoard?

Comment: I use xib file not Storyboard

Comment: @Kamran Second paragraph is my custom cell. I connect action as you see.

Comment: @RahulGUsai I made a break point in deleegate func method but has no sense. It doesnt enter delegate func!

Comment: @AliUral I don't believe! Put a breakPoint here `delegate?.searchCellShareButton(sender: self)` and tell us if your button is working.

Comment: means you delegate is not even calling

Comment: @RahulGUsai yes delegate is not calling. Kamran I added a pic

Comment: try this https://github.com/shaharukhs/CollectionViewActionProtocol I have created demo sample for you.

Comment: I copied and pasted your work it didnt work already. But your code works. I do a little mistake but i didnt find yet.

Comment: The difference with your code is " I call collectionview from another xib file but you create on your VC.". I added my VC

Comment: I tried with create collectionView in VC but error is continue.

Comment: @AliUral please check my new committed code is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Used the same code of your's and it is working perfectly fine. Can't figure out why it is not working at your end.

If you are not getting the solution try `Closures` :

```
class SecondCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var callbackOnButton : (()->())?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBAction func methodButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.callbackOnButton?()
    }
}
```

and in `cellForRowAtIndex` add :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SecondCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell


    cell.callbackOnButton = {
        print("Button Clicked")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "SearchCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SearchCollectionCell")
}
```

in your cell class

```
protocol SearchCollectionCellDelegate:class{
func searchCellShareButton(sender:SearchCollectionCell)
}

 class SearchCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

 @IBOutlet var searchImage: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet var productName: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet var productCompany: UILabel!

 weak var delegate:SearchCollectionCellDelegate?

override func layoutSubviews() {
searchImage.layer.cornerRadius = 4
}

@IBAction func cellShareButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

delegate?.searchCellShareButton(sender: self)

}
}
```

now go to your controller conform protocol

```
class yourViewController:UIVIewController, SearchCollectionCellDelegate{
 }
```

in you data source method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 guard let cell: SearchCollectionCell! = 
collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
"SearchCollectionCell", 
 for: indexPath) as? SearchCollectionCell else{return UICollectionViewCell() }

cell.delegate = self
return cell
 }
```

Comment: This is the same code as me already.It doesnt work dude. I dont see where is mistake . Thanks your advance. Also I tried your answer.

Comment: I know is not same but similat also I tried your stuff. Maybe it is about my last edit

Comment: check xib name you give it

Comment: Another 3 parameters come properly in Cell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered CollectionViewCell Class with proper identifier in your view controller...
if not try to register it in viewDidLoad Method.