# Swift: Table View Cell perform segue to two different destinations

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My question: 
I wanna perform segue to two different destinations in a table view cell. One is directing destination "A" by clicking the cell which handled by didSelectRowAt, **Another one is directing to destination "B" by clicking the button inside the cell, for example, the labelName.**

For destiation "B", I have try to use (btn.addTarget), but it cannot add parameters, so the destinatin view controller do not know the which cell was being clicked.

Any suggestion?

Comment: wanna try closures check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239746/swift-connect-delegate-to-custom-xib-cell/51242496#51242496

Answer (score 0):

you can use button.tag and assign the tag of every button with your indexpath.row

```
button.tag = indexPath.row
button.addTarget(self, action: "btnClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

func btnClick(sender:UIButton) {
    let buttonRow = sender.tag
}
```

for swift 4  :

```
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(händlerButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    @objc func händlerButtonTapped(sender:UIButton) {
       let buttonRow = sender.tag
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I can get the indexPath.row, but how can I get the information inside the cell, like the labelName inside one of the tableViewCell? I try to do something as follow but turns out it cannot retrieve the data.
    @objc func händlerButtonTapped(sender:UIButton) {
       let buttonRow = sender.tag
       let info:infoModel
       info = infoList[buttonRow]
       let name = info.labelName
       print("Name: \(name)")
    }
printedMessage:(Name: Prototype.infoModel)
it only showed the model name but not the value, is it a must to use didSelectRowAt to get the data inside the cell?

Comment: no it depends to your data structure, update your answer and add the function cellForRowAt, i want to see how you presenting your label ( func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell )

Answer (score 0):

You can Get the indexPath of your selected TableviewCell in your btnClick function by using this.

```
let index = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

Now by doing this you can solve this problem you mentioned.

> the destinatin view controller do not know the which cell was being clicked

Answer (score 0):

Here is my cellForRowAt:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! contentTableViewCell

    let content: contentModel
    content = contentList[indexPath.row]
    contentViewController().getUserProfilePic(userID:content.userID!)
    cell.detailLabelName.text = content.name
    cell.detailLabelTime.text = content.time
    cell.detailTextViewContent.text = content.content

    if UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey:content.userID!) != nil {
        cell.detailImageSelfie.image = UIImage(data:UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey:content.userID!)!)
    } else {
        cell.detailImageSelfie.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "defaultIcon")
    }
    return cell
}
```